# Populating an HTML table with MySQL data, linked by calendar date

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using the code below to generate a simple HTML table that displays the next 90 calendar days.  Each day is a row in this simple table.

```
$now = time();
echo "<table>";
for ($i=0;$i<90;$i++)
{
   $thisDate = date("d/m/Y",$now + ($i*86400));
   echo "<tr><td>".$thisDate."</td></tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Also, I have a MySQL table with the following fields:

```
event           varchar(1000)   
datescheduled   date
```

How can I make a second column in the aforementioned HTML table, containing "event" from the MySQL table, matched by date?

Answer (score 0):

This can be tackled in numerous ways. Consider this example:

PHP

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","dbuser","dbpass","database");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM event");

// First build the array of events, put the dates in keys, then the values as events
$events = array();
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $events[$result['datescheduled']] = $result['event'];
}

?>
```

---

```
// Structure should be something like this:
Array
(
    [2014-05-02] => Day of lorem
    [2014-06-02] => Day of ipsum
    [2014-07-02] => Day of days
)
```

---

HTML

```
<!-- the compare selected values on the current loop, check its keys -->

<?php $now = time(); ?>
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
<?php for($i=0;$i<90;$i++): ?>
    <?php $thisDate = date("Y-m-d", $now + ($i*86400)); ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $thisDate; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo array_key_exists($thisDate, $events) ? $events[$thisDate] : ''; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$now = time();
echo "<table>";
for ($i=0;$i<90;$i++)
{
   $thisDate = date("d/m/Y",$now + ($i*86400));
   echo "<tr><td>".$thisDate."</td>";
   $result_set = mysql_query("SELECT event FROM eventTable WHERE datescheduled = STR_TO_DATE('{$thisDate}','%d/%m/%Y')'",$connection);
   $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set);
   echo "<td>{$result['event']}</td></tr>\n";

}
echo "</table>";
```

Its worth noting that you will need to use a string to date function in mysql depending on how the date is stored.

Edit: in case you need further hand holding, here is the STR_TO_DATE function done for you.

```
STR_TO_DATE('{$thisDate}','%d/%m/%Y')
```

I have edited my code above to reflect this as to not strain your brain.

Even tossed in some screenshots of the table and the output, just because you were kind of an ass in your comment. With 5 years of experience i would have thought you would know how to echo out a simple table like this, or at the very least, have a little common courtesy when someone tries to help you.

[image: Table]

[image: Output]

Comment: What does the $connection mean?

Comment: To connect to a mysql database you must establish a connection, then call the connection when executing a query. $connection is the variable that you should store the connection to. You should review mysql_connection(), and mysql_query() functions in the PHP manual to get a better understanding of how they work :)

Comment: I've known about connecting to the database for about 5 years.  LOL.  This code you provided doesn't do what I want.

Comment: apparently not if you did not even understand the placement of a $connection variable in a query call. This code does exactly what you asked to do. It queries the database for the event corresponding to the current date in the table you are outputting and puts the event field in a second column in the HTML table. If that is not what you want, reword your question.