# HTML table of next 90 days, with corresponding events pulled from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have an HTML table that displays the next 90 days in the first column.  I'm trying to populate the 2nd column with events that correspond to the dates in the 1st column.

I tried the code below and it's not working; the 2nd column is blank.  In the MySQL table, the field "datescheduled" is type "date."

```
$now = time();
echo "<table class = 'samplesrec'>";
for ($i=0;$i<90;$i++)
{
   $thisDate = date("l, F j, Y",$now + ($i*86400));
   $deal = mysql_query("SELECT event, datescheduled FROM events WHERE datescheduled = '{$thisDate}'");
   $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($deal);
   echo "<tr><td>".$thisDate."</td><td>{$result['deal']}</td></tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Duplicate of your own question, [Populating an HTML table with MySQL data, linked by calendar date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419698/populating-an-html-table-with-mysql-data-linked-by-calendar-date)

Comment: Definitely similar.  Do you know how I can get the HTML table to work?

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL-String you have written `{$thisdate}` you shoud take `{$thisDate}`.

Comment: try to print your SQL-String and execute it on the Database and look if you get a result.

Comment: echo "SELECT event, datescheduled FROM events WHERE datescheduled = '{$thisDate}'" then you can see in your borwser the SQL-String

Comment: How could I put it into the HTML table?

Comment: try this:
for ($i=0;$i<90;$i++)
{
   $thisDate = date("l, F j, Y",$now + ($i*86400));
   $sql ="SELECT event, datescheduled FROM events WHERE datescheduled = '{$thisDate}'";
   $deal = mysql_query($sql);
   $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($deal);
   echo "<tr><td>".$thisDate."</td><td>{$sql}</td></tr>\n";
}

Comment: So your SQL isn't correct, what format have your datescheduled in database?

Comment: "datescheduled" is type "date."

Comment: Try $date = date("Y-m-d",$now + ($i*86400)); and add $date to your SQL-String.